shift + enter does opens new terminal and does not implement in current terminal
I have a current session running python in VSCode.
I use shift + enter to send a line of code to the terminal.
Occassionally, I take a break for 10min, and with the current terminal and editor open, run a line with shift + enter. Instead of running the line to the current terminal, a new terminal is started.
How can I ensure that when I run a line, it stays on the current terminal? It is a little annoying to have to start an entire script again to get a live terminal active avain
